# Why does this code compile with gcc but not with clang

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, clang++

This code works perfectly fine with gcc/g++ and msvc but not with clang.
It keeps complaining that no matching function for Log was found, what is going on?

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename Function, typename... Args>
auto Call(Function func, Args&&... args) -> typename std::result_of<Function&(Args&&...)>::type
{
    return func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template <typename T, typename... Args>
T (*Log( T (*FuncPtr)(Args...) ))(Args...)
{
    return FuncPtr;
}

int main()
{
    auto r = Log(Call<int(int), int>)([](int x){
        return x*10;
    }, 10);
    std::cerr << r << std::endl;
}
```

Error:

```
> error: no matching function for call to 'Log'
>     auto r = Log(Call<int(int), int>)([](int x){
>              ^~~ test7.cpp:15:5: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T' T (*Log( T (*FuncPtr)(Args...)
> ))(Args...)
>     ^ 1 error generated.
```

Comment: Even simpler: `auto call = Call<int(int), int>;` fails with `error: variable 'call' with type 'auto' has incompatible initializer of type '<overloaded function type>'`. The issue with `Log` is a red herring, the problem starts earlier - the compiler seems to have trouble figuring out what type `Call<int(int), int>` is.

Comment: Works if you replace `result_of`dance with `decltype(func(args...))`

Comment: Why is there an ampersand symbol `std::result_of<Function &( ...)>`? That looks out of place to me.

Comment: @ChrisBeck Removing that ampersand doesn't help any, though. It's not the root of the problem.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik well, is this something related to clang? Because this code works on msvc++ as well.

Comment: @ChrisBeck That's actually correct; you are calling the function object as an lvalue.

Comment: Even better, replace `typename std::result_of<...>::type` with `std::result_of_t<...>` and clang compiles it. That's... weird.

Comment: @Barry: That is super wierd, I've only seen a bug like that one other time, which I reported a few months ago: https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=26586 In that case it was kind of the reverse though. In that case, if you "inline" a helper template kind of like `std::result_of_t`, it actually prevents an ICE. It sounds like a clang bug to me.

Comment: @ChrisBeck I threw out [27918](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=27918), we'll see what smarter people say.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that this code is incorrect. The function parameter to `Log` cannot be used for template argument deduction in this case because the argument is a non-deduced context.

From [temp.deduct.type] in the standard, p5 lists the non-deduced contexts, and p5.5 says:

> A function parameter for which argument deduction cannot be done
>   because the associated function argument is a function, or a set of
>   overloaded functions (13.4), and one or more of the following apply:

and p5.5.3 says:

> the set of functions supplied as an argument contains one or more
>   function templates.

My interpretation is that you have a function parameter for which the function argument is a (pointer to) a function and that function is a function template.

Arguably, because this isn't an overload set, this might be something that could be allowed in the future, but I read the standard as not guaranteeing that this technique will work.